# ImportError when debugging but not when running in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, kivy, importerror

I am building a desktop app using the python library Kivy. Since I installed a plugin to be able to visualize .kv files, I am not able to debug my code. Yet I am able to run it without problems. This is the error I keep getting:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "...\Worktime_Tool\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 416, in <module>
     from os.path import dirname, join, exists, sep, expanduser, isfile
 ImportError: cannot import name 'sep' from 'ntpath' (...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ntpath.py)
```

So far I do not understand where this `ntpath` stands for. I tried to compare the `ntpath` while debugging and while running and they are the same. I also double checked that the interpreter set for the prrject and the interpreter in the run/debug configurations are the same.

I tried with and without the usage of a `venv` .

Does anyone have an idea why I can run this app but not debug it?

Appreciate much the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago.  You can either edit the \lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py in your virtual environment to remove the sep from that import line on line 416.

It will look like this after you remove the sep.

```
from os.path import dirname, join, exists, expanduser, isfile
```

Or

Update to the latest version of kivy which no longer gives me the error.

You can update to the latest kivy developer build with this command:

```
python -m pip install "kivy[base] @ https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip"
```